# Question on angular acceleration in OCR A Level further maths textbook

Tags: physics

OCR A Level Further maths: mechanics, Year $1.$

Chapter $4$ Section $2$: Acceleration in horizontal circular motion.

> $\omega$ is angular speed and is defined as $\frac{d\theta}{d t},$ sometimes written as $\overset{.}{\theta}.$
> An equation for linear (tangential) speed is then derived and is given
> by: $v=r\omega...$ $$$$... The formula for acceleration is given by $a=v\omega.$
> Since $v=r\omega,$ you can write $a=r\omega^2$ (note that this equals
> $r\overset{.}{\theta}^2$ ) and, since $\omega = \frac{v}{r},$ you can
> write $a=\frac{v^2}{r}.$

One the side there is a "tip":

> Sometimes acceleration is written as $a=r\overset{..}{\theta},$ where
> $\overset{..}{\theta}=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}.$

But surely this means that $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \overset{.}{\theta}^2,$ which is false.

So is the "tip" wrong, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I find the text slightly hard to read; due to the notation jumping around. Maybe more consistency, like this, better: $$r\quad\overset{.}r\quad\overset{..}r \\
r\quad v\quad a\\\quad\\
\theta\quad\overset{.}\theta\quad\overset{..}\theta\\
\theta\quad\omega\quad\alpha$$

> > An equation for linear (tangential) speed is then derived and is given
> > by $$v=r\omega.$$

This is the linear speed of circular motion.

> > The formula for acceleration is given by $a=v\omega.$
> > Since $v=r\omega,$ you can write $a=r\omega^2$ and, since $\omega = \frac{v}{r},$ you can
> > write $$a=\frac{v^2}{r}.$$

This “$a$” is the **centripetal** acceleration of circular motion; let's relabel it $a_{\text{centripetal}}.$

> > Sometimes acceleration is written as $$a=r\overset{..}{\theta}$$

This “$a$” is the **tangential** acceleration of circular motion; let's relabel it $a_{\text{tangential}}.$ For *uniform* circular motion, that is, when the angular acceleration $\overset{..}{\theta}$ equals $0,$ this quantity equals $0.$

> But surely this means that $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} =
> \overset{.}{\theta}^2,$ which is false.

Since $a_{\text{centripetal}}$ does not generally equal $a_{\text{tangential}},$ the above is indeed false.

(The linear acceleration of circular motion is the vector sum of $a_{\text{centripetal}}$ and $a_{\text{tangential}}.$)

P.S. Here's a nice summary: [A Tale of Three Accelerations, or The Differences between Angular, Tangential, and Centripetal Accelerations](https://www.flippingphysics.com/uploads/2/1/1/0/21103672/0230_lecture_notes_-_a_tale_of_three_accelerations_or_the_differences_between_angular_tangential_and_centripetal_accelerations.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are combining steps from rotational and translational.

Using the definitions and following through as below, should highlight the differences you have in your steps.

$$
\omega = \frac{v_t}{r}\\
\alpha = \frac{a_t}{r}
$$
where rotational is on the left side

$$
a_t = \frac{dv_t}{dt}\\
\alpha = \frac{d\omega}{dt}
$$

so we an denote $\alpha$ using the translational acc definition.
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{r}\frac{dv_t}{dt} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}r\omega = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}r\dot{\theta}\\
$$
or directly using the rotational velocity
$$
\alpha = \frac{d}{dt}\dot{\theta}
$$

Comment: "I think the issue is you are combining steps from rotational and translational." Are you saying I am the one doing this, or the book is? The questions from my question are from the book and All I have done is combined the two different definitions of acceleration the book gives and combining them to come up with a new equation. Also, please can you clearly define what those variables $a_t$ and $v_t$ are?

Comment: subscript `t` is for translational. Are you are talking about centripetal vs rotational velocities/accelerations? Since centripetal gives the equations you have given above. $a_c = r\omega^2$ vs $\alpha_r = r\frac{d\omega}{dt}$

Comment: So basically, $a=r\omega^2$ is the translational acceleration, meaning the magnitude of instantaneous acceleration in the usual $x-y$ plane sense. And your $\alpha$ is the (definition of) rotational acceleration? Is this correct? If so, they have not used two different symbols for these two different things in the book, which is confusing.

Comment: It is more than that - I will update the post. But in the mean time review this [translational-rotational-centripetal Table 10.3](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/10-3-relating-angular-and-translational-quantities)